# Group by quarter (datepart) returns multiple rows with same quarter

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to return a count for the total number of records in the table HISTORY grouped by their quarter and year. Currently I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CAST(DATEPART(year, CREATE_DATE) AS char) + ' Qtr' + 
                CAST(DATEPART(quarter, CREATE_DATE) AS char)) AS Period,
       COUNT(ID)
FROM HISTORY
GROUP BY CREATE_DATE
ORDER BY Period;
```

But I'm getting duplicate rows with the same quarter and year. I'm also getting a total of records counted that's lower than the total records in the table. [Here's a sample sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/85def/8) in case that helps identify the problem.

I wouldn't have thought I'd need to specify DISTINCT in the period column either, but when I don't I get even more dupes... which I'm guessing is part of the same root problem.

Comment: Look closely. The code does what you wrote, not what you want. You group by create_date so you get a row for each unique value of create_date. The fact that you only display a value composed of year and quarter does not affect your grouping. You need to group by year and quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ist that you are grouping by CREATE_DATE but want to group by year and quarter:

```
SELECT 
  DATENAME(year, CREATE_DATE) + ' Qtr' + DATENAME(quarter, CREATE_DATE) AS Period,
  COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords
FROM HISTORY
GROUP BY DATENAME(year, CREATE_DATE), DATENAME(quarter, CREATE_DATE)
ORDER BY Period;
```

Comment: I tried grouping by the column that I had named (like you can do `ORDER BY`) but that just wouldn't compute. I didn't think to specify multiple values to group by, which was dumb of me!

Also thanks for pointing out the `DATENAME` function! That'll save some space!

Comment: @IsaacReefman The only reason for the sorting by the column name works is that it takes place in the very end after calculating the result. The grouping takes place long before, so you would have to repeat the formula in the GROUP BY clause (which wasn't too bad, because SQL Server is clever enough to evaluate the expression only once). As you see, grouping by multiple values isn't "dumb", instead sometimes it's useful. You wanted to see the number of records by quarter, but of course the quarter belongs to a year. Grouping by the date was too granular. Thank you, happy that you liked it!