# Grouping aggregated data in separate tables

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, outer-join

Related to my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352832/group-by-quarter-datepart-returns-multiple-rows-with-same-quarter), I'm trying to `COUNT` records in a `HISTORY` table and an `OPPORTUNITIES` table, and group them by the year and quarter of their `CREATE_DATE`s.

I want one row in the results grid for each quarter, with one column for `HISTORY` records and one for `OPPORTUNITIES` records:

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+
| Quarter | History Items | Opportunities |
+---------+---------------+---------------+
| 2017 Q1 |            15 |            25 |
| 2017 Q2 |            12 |            16 |
| 2017 Q3 |            13 |            18 |
| 2017 Q4 |            16 |            20 |
| 2018 Q1 |            17 |            18 |
+---------+---------------+---------------+
```

I can get the results I want for either table, but as soon as I try to join them I end up with issues. I've tried various `JOIN` and `UNION` versions, but can't seem to get it right. I can see potential issues in the coding with everything I try, but can't work out how to code something that won't have them. This is the working single table `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT DATENAME(year, H.CREATE_DATE) + ', Qtr' + DATENAME(quarter, H.CREATE_DATE) AS Period,
       COUNT(H.ID) AS [History Items]
FROM   HISTORY AS H 
GROUP BY DATENAME(year, H.CREATE_DATE), DATENAME(quarter, H.CREATE_DATE)
ORDER BY Period;
```

And one of the versions I've tried to add the second table:

```
SELECT DATENAME(year, O.CREATE_DATE) + ', Qtr' + DATENAME(quarter, O.CREATE_DATE) AS Period,
       COUNT(O.ID) AS Opportunities,
       COUNT(H.ID) AS [History Items]
FROM   OPPORTUNITY AS O FULL JOIN
       HISTORY AS H ON DATENAME(year, O.CREATE_DATE) + DATENAME(quarter, O.CREATE_DATE) =
                       DATENAME(year, H.CREATE_DATE) + DATENAME(quarter, H.CREATE_DATE)
GROUP BY DATENAME(year, O.CREATE_DATE), DATENAME(quarter, O.CREATE_DATE)
ORDER BY Period;
```

For easy testing and further clarity, [here is a sample database with what I've been working on in sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8d09/13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to use `UNION ALL` to join both of the result. This is probably clearer and easier. You may also use `FULL OUTER JOIN` as what you attempted, but with `CTE` or `derivied table`

```
; WITH 
hist as
(
     -- your hist query 
    SELECT DATENAME(year, H.CREATE_DATE) 
           + ', Qtr' + DATENAME(quarter, H.CREATE_DATE) AS Period,
           COUNT(H.ID) AS [History Items]
    FROM   HISTORY AS H 
    GROUP BY DATENAME(year, H.CREATE_DATE), DATENAME(quarter, H.CREATE_DATE)
),
opp as
(
     -- the opportunity query
     SELECT DATENAME(year, O.CREATE_DATE) 
            + ', Qtr' + DATENAME(quarter, O.CREATE_DATE) AS Period,
            COUNT(O.ID) AS [Opportunities]
     FROM   OPPORTUNITY AS O
     GROUP BY DATENAME(year, O.CREATE_DATE), DATENAME(quarter, O.CREATE_DATE)
),
CTE as
(
     -- union both query together
     SELECT Period, [History Items], [Opportunities] = 0
     FROM   hist h
     UNION ALL
     SELECT Period, [History Items] = 0, Opportunities
     FROM   Oppr
)
-- final result
SELECT Period, 
       [History Items] = SUM([History Items]), 
       [Opportunities] = SUM([Opportunities])
FROM   CTE
GROUP BY Period
ORDER BY Period

-- FULL OUTER JOIN version. using the same hist & opp from previous query
SELECT Period = COALESCE(h.Period, o.Period),
       [History Items] = SUM([History Items]), 
       [Opportunities] = SUM([Opportunities])
FROM   hist h
       FULL OUTER JOIN opp o ON h.Period = o.Period
GROUP BY COALESCE(h.Period, o.Period)
ORDER BY Period
```

Comment: I've not seen `; WITH` before... what's that?

Comment: that is for `Common Table Expression` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm trying it out as is, but also trying to work out if there's a way to do it without CTE, as I suspect the parser which is based on SQL Server but appears to be *VERY* limited might not work with them...

Comment: you can also use `DERIVED TABLE` instead of `CTE`. If this also does not work, you may also consider create 2 views, one for the history and another for the opportunities

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but not because it isn't right - my software I'm trying to work with is frustratingly limited, but the limitations are not specified anywhere I can find them... Not sure how I'm going to implement this concept yet, still looking. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: which portion of the query that the software is complaining ?

Comment: At the moment I've reduced it down just to `SELECT COUNT(H.HISTORYID) AS [History Items] FROM   dbo.HISTORY AS H` and it's still getting me an empty grey box. It's inside an xml framework that I've triple checked along with the names of the fields and tables, and there are other examples (that work fine) that use `COUNT` and the same syntax for aliases, so I'm getting pretty frustrated...